# R copy to inkscape 0.92

Tags: r, plot, copy-paste, inkscape, metafile

I'm new using R. My friends usually use inkscape for finishing their R plots. They use RStudio and Inkscape v0.92, after they make the plots in RStudio

```
Export > Copy to Clipboard > Copy as Metafile > Copy Plot
```

Then simply `Ctrl + V` in inkscape. But when I do that, the pasted plot in inkscape is completly destroyed.

My example:

In RStudio

```
data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25) 
par(pty="s")
qqnorm(data, pch=19, cex = 0.8, xlab = "Quantis Teóricos", ylab= "Amostra", las=1, 
        main="Gráfico QQ", lwd = 0.25, cex.main=1.0, cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75,
       font.lab=2, xlim=c(-5,5), xaxs="r", yaxs="r")
 qqline(data, lwd = 0.25)
 grid(4, 5, lwd = 0.25)
 box(lwd = 0.25)
```

[image: Image Here]

Then, when I `Ctrl + V` in inkscape, I get

[image: a little zoom]

Any one knows how to fix it???

Comment: I'm very thankful for Inkscape - great tool! - but compared to the good old 0.48, the newer versions all seem like a disimprovement to me. Pasting worked fine in 0.48, so you might want to grab that if you can...

Answer (score 2):

In reference to this [link](http://keziamanlove.com/touching-up-plots-in-inkscape/);

You should not copy/paste into inkspace but make an output of `*.svg` to later edit it in that environment.

```
mypath <- "Path/to/the/desired/folder/myplot.svg" #Edit the path as you wish
svg(mypath, width = 8, height = 10)

data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25) 
par(pty="s")
qqnorm(data, pch=19, cex = 0.8, xlab = "Quantis Teóricos", ylab= "Amostra", las=1, 
    main="Gráfico QQ", lwd = 0.25, cex.main=1.0, cex.lab=0.75, cex.axis=0.75,
   font.lab=2, xlim=c(-5,5), xaxs="r", yaxs="r")
 qqline(data, lwd = 0.25)
 grid(4, 5, lwd = 0.25)
 box(lwd = 0.25)

dev.off()
```

This will give you a file that you can later edit in Inkspace.